# Migrating word requests within a field with an existing tag

Tags: discussion, tags, appropriate-questions, migration

In [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362879/what-is-the-psychological-term-for-a-person-who-avoids-a-question-by-bashing-or), a user suggested that the question should be migrated because of the lack of expertise in this forum in the area that the OP was requesting a term for. However, the user tagged the question with an existing tag.

Why would a single word request that asks for a word within a field that has an existing tag need to be migrated? Examples of tags are legal, animal, psychology, linguistics, sociolinguistics, psycholinguistics, medical, and many nore.

Comment: I saw the comments by @ Mick and @ Laurel. For Mick's comment, you need to read the original version as it was even more unclear than the edited version. For Laurel's comment, he just introduced an SE site that is not well-known to other users. Just because a few users left a comment to say ELU is not the right place to ask about clinical terminology or introduce a site doesn't mean it should be migrated. The question received two close-votes and the reasons were all *unclear*. In addition, you need to note that just because there is a tag doesn't mean it is on-topic. I think the Q is unclear.

Comment: I'm not clear on your complaint. Why does having a tag prevent an question, SWR or otherwise, from being migrated?

Comment: @Mitch, this is a question. It's not a complaint.

Comment: Ok question. But I still don't understand it. I don't understand why you think the migration was necessary. It was not. But you seem to think a tag prevents or forces a migration. How does that work then? Or explain how I've misunderstood you.

Comment: How you've misunderstood me is that I think the migration is *not* necessary. I am trying to ask why a question would be migrated to Cognitive because it asks about a psychological term, even though there is a tag for psychology. (Though as it turns out this may not be why is was suggested to be migrated, although one commenter was sure it should not be asked on ELU.) Is there a way you would suggest rephrasing the question that would make that clearer to you? Thanks.

Comment: @JEL thank you for answering. That clears up my question.

Comment: @JEL Please consider converting your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags are ad hoc. That one exists and has been added to a question has no bearing on whether the question should or should not be migrated, closed, etc.